# R does not work since update to version 3.3.2

Tags: r, opensuse

Since the latest update to version 3.3.2 I get the following error when trying to start R.

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)

[...] 

 Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/utils/libs/utils.so':
/usr/lib64/R/library/utils/libs/utils.so: undefined symbol: csduplicated
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package "methods" in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: S3 methods ‘[.getAnywhere’, ‘[.roman’, ‘as.character.person’,‘as.character.roman’, ‘as.person.default’, ‘as.personList.default’, ‘as.personList.person’, ‘close.txtProgressBar’, ‘edit.data.frame’, ‘edit.default’, ‘edit.matrix’, ‘edit.vignette’, ‘format.news_db’, ‘format.object_size’, ‘format.roman’, ‘head.data.frame’, ‘head.default’, ‘head.function’, ‘head.matrix’, ‘head.ftable’, ‘head.table’, ‘print.aspell’, ‘print.aspell_inspect_context’, ‘print.Bibtex’, ‘print.changedFiles’, ‘print.fileSnapshot’, ‘print.findLineNumResult’, ‘print.getAnywhere’, ‘print.hsearch’, ‘print.help_files_with_topic’, ‘print.Latex’, ‘print.ls_str’, ‘print.MethodsFunction’, ‘print.news_db’, ‘print.object_size’, ‘print.packageDescription’, ‘print.packageIQR’, ‘print.packageStatus’, ‘print.roman’, ‘print.sessionInfo’, ‘print.socket’, ‘print.summary.p [... truncated]                                                                                         
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath,...) :        
unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so':                                                                           
/usr/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so: undefined symbol: mbcsToUcs2                                                                             
In addition: Warning messages:                                                                                                                               
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found                                                                                               
2: S3 methods ‘print.recordedplot’, ‘print.colorConverter’, ‘print.RGBcolorConverter’, ‘checkFont.default’, ‘checkFont.Type1Font’, ‘checkFont.CIDFont’, ‘matchEncoding.Type1Font’, ‘matchEncoding.CIDFont’, ‘as.raster.raster’, ‘as.raster.logical’, ‘as.raster.numeric’, ‘as.raster.character’, ‘as.raster.matrix’, ‘as.raster.array’, ‘as.matrix.raster’, ‘is.na.raster’, ‘anyNA.raster’, ‘[.raster’, ‘[<-.raster’, ‘Ops.raster’, ‘print.raster’, ‘pretty.Date’, ‘pretty.POSIXt’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found                              
[...]
```

I have OpenSUSE 13.2.; R-patched.

I tried to uninstall and re-install R in YaST, but that did not help.

ldd for utils.so gives the following:

```
ldd /usr/lib64/R/library/utils/libs/utils.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcaa53c000)
    libR.so => /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so (0x00007f769e25a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f769deb0000)
    libRblas.so => /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so (0x00007f769dc82000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f769d981000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f769d739000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f769d4cc000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f769d2a6000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f769d097000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f769ce80000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f769cc78000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f769ca74000)
    libicuuc.so.53.1 => /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.53.1 (0x00007f769c6f1000)
    libicui18n.so.53.1 => /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.53.1 (0x00007f769c2ae000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f769c09f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f769be81000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f769eab2000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f769bc4d000)
    libicudata.so.53.1 => /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.53.1 (0x00007f769ba4b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f769b743000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f769b52c000)
```

What is wrong? How can I get R to run agian?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You may look into using R-patched on openSuse. This version is constantly updated, and I haven't had any problems with it in 5+ years. There are directions on CRAN. You have to set up a repository with either zypper or yast.

Comment: If you don't get a reply here you may try the [openSuse foruns](https://forums.opensuse.org/) (or R's if they have one). I hope you get to work, trying R on openSuse is on my todo list...

Comment: @lmo Thanks for your comment. I am using R-patched. (I have now indicated this in the question.) The problem occured after an automatic udate.

Comment: @keszei I tried updating to the latest version of 3.3.2 using version openSuse 42.1, but was not able to do so. zypper would not allow the update. It appears from looking at the error message and at the contents of the repository that the R-base-3.2.3 RPM is missing. This may be an oversight of the maintainer. I'd follow Rolazaro's advice and ask on the opensuse forums. If you don't get a response there, I believe there is a way to contact the openSuse R maintainer on the CRAN website.

Comment: I successfully updated R to 3.3.2 patched as follows: Type this into the console `sudo zypper remove R-core` then say yes once or twice, then enter `sudo install R-patched` and say yes once or twice.

Comment: @Sylvain asks (now-deleted question):  R-patched is not found in Suse42.1 package name. Did you add a specific repo to get it ? (And I think you forgot 'zypper' in your second command: shouldn't it be 'sudo zypper install R-Patched' ?...)